# Which coroutine scope to use when rotating fragments? Can we launch a coroutine from a viewmodel?

Tags: android, rotation, fragment, kotlin-coroutines, android-jetpack

In a fragment, when performing a save operation via a coroutine, which type of scope should be used **taking as the main consideration** that rotating the device should not stop the coroutine?

And where should I keep the coroutine **Job** reference, in order to allow the user to cancel it at any moment while still executing? even after rotation, if desired? If I place the job in a `ViewModel` in order to recover it after a device `rotation`, would it be leaking a fragment's `lifecycleScope`?

I am aware that a fragment has a scope, such as:

```
fragment.lifecycleScope.launch(context = Dispatchers.IO)
```

but I am not sure if this is the correct one to use, as I assume that rotating the device may cancel it.

Also, I am not sure if the next one would be right:

```
CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Within a `ViewModel` u can `launch {}` a coroutine using `viewmodelscope` like"-

```
viewModelScope.launch {
    // Coroutine that will be canceled when the ViewModel is cleared.
}
```

Then you can use `liveData` to communicate with `fragment` since both liveData and viewmodel are lifecycle aware it would handle the rotation scenarios too.

It should solve your purpose.

To use `viewModelScope` we need lifecycle version `2.2.0` and above

```
// ViewModel
implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:2.2.0"
```